# Opening a file with code breaks formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open another workbook, so I execute this code:

```
Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(PathFile)
```

If I open the file with this code some formulas have #names errors.
If I open the file manually (without vba) I have no errors at all.
If I open the file with this code, get the errors, save the file and open it   manually, errors remain. If I validate all formulas one by one from the beginning the formulas work again.
There are no external links to any other workbooks in this file.

I don't understand at all why opening a file with VBA code is different than open it manually?

How can I find the source of this bug?

Comment: Can you give an example of such formula?

Comment: A specific named range cause all the trouble. I don't know why. Very strange. I will work without it until I find the solution.